# Static code checker complaining. False alarm?

Tags: c++

Using VS2017 community, when I compile the following code, it issues a warning coming from the static code checker:

> > Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> >     Warning C26495  Variable 'aux::system::Dummy::value' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    80  Active

Am I doing something wrong or is this a false alarm?

Here, the code causing this (minus the namespace surrounding it...):

```
class Dummy
{
    const uint32_t value;
public:
    Dummy() = delete;
    Dummy( const Dummy& other )
        : value{ other.value }
    {}
    explicit Dummy( uint32_t v)
        : value{ v }
    {}
};
```

I cannot see why the `value` member could ever go uninitialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong or is this a false alarm?

It seems to be a false positive on **C26495**.

Several similar reports can also be found. ([Link1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/321981/c26495-false-positive-with-default-member-initiali.html)), ([Link2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/297884/c26495-reports-false-positives.html))

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, definitely a false positive … I get this warning often in very similar code. An easy (though annoyingly unnecessary) way to get round it is to add an initializer brace to the member **declaration**:

```
const uint32_t value{ 0 };
```

Not sure why the code analyser makes this mistake - possibly because you haven't defined an assignment operator? More likely just a bug, though!

Edit: In VS2019 (Community) your code gives:

```
warning C4626:  'Dummy': assignment operator was implicitly defined as deleted
```

But when I add:

```
Dummy& operator = (Dummy& rhs) = delete;
```

to the class, I don't get your 26495 warning!?