# Warning C26495 for initialized static variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I really don't understand why I'm getting warning C26495 in my constructor regarding `m_pszDriverPreferred` and `m_pszDriverSearchTerms`.

**Header File**

```
class CMyClass : CBaseClass
{
private:
    static LPCTSTR m_pszDriverPreferred;
    static LPCTSTR m_pszDriverSearchTerms;

public:
    CMyClass(LPCTSTR pszArg1, LPCTSTR pszArg2);
    ~CMyClass();
};
```

**Source File**

```
LPCTSTR CMyClass::m_pszDriverPreferred = _T("Blah, blah, blah");
LPCTSTR CMyClass::m_pszDriverSearchTerms = _T("Blah, blah, blah");

CMyClass::CMyClass(LPCTSTR pszDriver, LPCTSTR pszConnectionString) // <<<- WARNING HERE!
    : CBaseClass(pszDriver, pszConnectionString)
{
}
```

**Warning**

> MyFile(11): warning C26495: Variable 'CMyClass::m_pszDriverPreferred' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).
>
> MyFile(11): warning C26495: Variable 'CMyClass::m_pszDriverSearchTerms' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).

First of all, these variables *have* been initialized, as you can see above. And second, why would I get this warning on an instance constructor when the variables are static?

Does anyone know any angle where this warning makes sense here?

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @NathanOliver: The very latest. Just updated a couple of days ago.

Comment: The new code analysis in VS is awful. It keeps warning me about totally legitimate code. I've turned it off.

Comment: What's in `CBaseClass`?

Comment: There are various [false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825816/static-code-checker-complaining-false-alarm) associated with this warning.

Comment: @john: I feel like I've been able to make some sense of most of the warnings.

Comment: @JonathanWood I agree, I've not had anything like this example here where the warning just seems bogus. But I have had plenty where a little bit of analysis would show that the warning cannot apply. There's no point is analysis that most of the time is flagging legitimate code as you're just going to ignore any genuine issues.

Comment: If you can make those class members `const`, you can provide an initializer in the class definition, e.g. `class MyClass { static LPCTSTR const m_psz = _T("blah"); };`. If you cannot make it `const` but are using C++17, you can declare the variable `inline`, and provide an initializer as well. See [static members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) for details. I'm not sure this will silence the warning; you'd have to try this yourself.

Comment: On a second thought, unlike you, the compiler cannot really see, that the static variable is in fact initialized. It's the linker, that puts the final pieces together, required by the CRT's startup code to run those static initializers.

Comment: Aahh! Another dodgy Code Analysis warning. I've been coming across lots of these lately (here on SO and after recently using it in my VS projects). This one is really odd, though. I've added code to emulate OP's issue in one of my classes: already has a member `static int runApp;` and I added `static LPCWSTR cIssue;` In the **same file** (immediately after the end of the class declaration) I have `int MyClass::runApp = 0;` and added `LPCWSTR MyClass::cIssue = "Blah, blah, blah";`. Only get the initialization warning for the string, not for the int!

Comment: @IInspectable: the LPCTSTR definition includes the const attribute!

Comment: @adr: `LPCTSTR` expands to `TCHAR const*`. `LPCTSTR const` expands to `TCHAR const* const`. With pointers, there are two entities that can be `const`: The pointer and the pointee.

Answer (score 3):

I have no clue why this works, but does for me in very similar code! Try the seemingly trivial edits as indicated below:

```
class CMyClass : CBaseClass
{
private:
//  static LPCTSTR m_pszDriverPreferred;
//  static LPCTSTR m_pszDriverSearchTerms;
    static const TCHAR* m_pszDriverPreferred;
    static const TCHAR* m_pszDriverSearchTerms;

public:
    CMyClass(LPCTSTR pszArg1, LPCTSTR pszArg2);
    ~CMyClass();
};

//LPCTSTR CMyClass::m_pszDriverPreferred = _T("Blah, blah, blah");
//LPCTSTR CMyClass::m_pszDriverSearchTerms = _T("Blah, blah, blah");
const TCHAR* CMyClass::m_pszDriverPreferred = _T("Blah, blah, blah");
const TCHAR* CMyClass::m_pszDriverSearchTerms = _T("Blah, blah, blah");
```

Maybe something to do with the 'complex' typedef for LPCTSTR in the VS headers? (Uses _Null_terminated_ macro/attribute, which itself is defined as a _SAL2_Source_ macro!)